# shell piping and the cat command... on Windows

Tags: windows, command, cmd, pipe, cat

With most Unix shells, we can use the powers of pipe and the cat command to concatenate non-text data like the following example:

```
a_command_with_binary_output | cat - this_is_a_binary_file > output_file
```

What is the equivalent of the above command in Windows? I'm only targeting command.com or cmd.exe. No powershell please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you can spare the temporary space:

```
a_command_with_binary_output > temp_file
copy /B temp_file + this_is_a_binary_file output_file
del temp_file
```

But do yourself a favor and get [coreutils for Win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm). That contains `cat` and a bunch of other handy utilities.